# I2C: Raspberry Pi (Master) read Arduino (Slave)

Tags: perl, arduino, raspberry-pi, i2c, smbus

I would like to read a block of data from my Arduino Mega (and also from an Arduino Micro in another project) with my Raspberry Pi via I2C. The code has to be in Perl because it's sort of a plug-in for my Home-Automation-Server.

I'm using the `Device::SMBus` interface and the connection works, I'm able to write and read single Bytes. I can even use `writeBlockData` with register address `0x00`. I randomly discovererd that this address works.

But when I want to `readBlockData`, no register-address seems to work.

Does anyone know the correct register-address, or is that not even the problem that causes errors?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First off, which register(s) are you wanting to read? Here's an example using my [RPi::I2C](https://metacpan.org/pod/RPi::I2C) software (it should be exceptionally similar with the distribution you're using), along with a sketch that has a bunch of pseudo-registers configured for reading/writing.

First, the Perl code. It reads two bytes (the output of an `analogRead()` of pin `A0` which is set up as register `80`), then bit-shifts the two bytes into a 16-bit integer to get the full 0-1023 value of the pin:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use RPi::I2C;

my $arduino_addr = 0x04;

my $arduino = RPi::I2C->new($arduino_addr);

my @bytes = $arduino->read_block(2, 80);

my $a0_value = ($bytes[0] << 8) | $bytes[1];

print "$a0_value\n";
```

Here's a full-blown [Arduino sketch](https://github.com/stevieb9/rpi-wiringpi/blob/master/docs/sketch/arduino.ino) you can review that sets up a half dozen or so pseudo-registers, and when each register is specified, the Arduino writes or reads the appropriate data. If no register is specified, it operates on `0x00` register.

The I2C on the Arduino always does an `onReceive()` call before it does the `onRequest()` (when using `Wire`), so I set up a global variable `reg` to hold the register value, which I populate in the `onReceive()` interrupt, which is then used in the `onRequest()` call to send you the data at the pseudo-register you've specified.

The sketch itself doesn't really do anything useful, I just presented it as an example. It's actually part of my [automated unit test platform](https://fastapi.metacpan.org/source/STEVEB/RPi-WiringPi-2.3620/docs/breadboard/brewbuild_test_platform_bb.jpg) for my [RPi::WiringPi](https://metacpan.org/pod/RPi::WiringPi) distribution.